# Discord bot having trouble adding lots of roles... complains about event listeners

Tags: node.js, events, listener, discord.js, dom-events

I have a discord bot that updates a leaderboard channel on our discord. Each time a game is recorded in the database, the bot gets the leaderboard data, then for each memberId it comes across, it removes all the skill badges (higher skill equals more prestigious badge), then adds the correct badge based on their current skill. For some reason, adding a lot of member roles in succession is causing the bot to only get through about 15 or so members out of the top 100. I'm pretty new to js, but I think each addRole command is triggering a GuildMemberUpdate event, and it's just too much to handle. Here is the warning message I get. It's followed by a ton of adding role timeout errors (I'll include one).

```
(node:612) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberUpdate listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:280:19)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:297:10)
    at Promise (/home/ubuntu/bots/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:511:19)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at RESTMethods.addMemberRole (/home/ubuntu/bots/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:501:12)
    at GuildMember.addRole (/home/ubuntu/bots/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildMember.js:453:37)
    at C6Leaderboard.applyTags (/home/ubuntu/bots/modules/leaderboard.js:139:17)
    at C6Leaderboard.createLeaderboard (/home/ubuntu/bots/modules/leaderboard.js:110:18)
    at C6Leaderboard.publishLeaderboard (/home/ubuntu/bots/modules/leaderboard.js:67:29)
    at <anonymous>
Error: Adding the role timed out.
    at timeout.client.setTimeout (/home/ubuntu/bots/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RESTMethods.js:514:16)
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/ubuntu/bots/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:433:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

Here is the gist of my module's code:

```
class C6Leaderboard
{
    constructor() {
        util.client.on('ready', () =>
        {
            guild = util.client.guilds.get("291751672106188800");
            this.generate(); //generate an up to date leaderboard
        });
    }

    async generate()
    {
        try
        {
            // Grab data
            this.leaderboard = await util.makeRGRequest('leaderboard.php', {});

            // Publish new Leaderboard
            this.publishLeaderboard();
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log('[leaderboard_err]' + err);
        }
    }

    async publishLeaderboard()
    {
        const channel = util.getChannel(483346000233365526);
        const msg = await channel.fetchMessage(channel.lastMessageID());
        const content_new = this.createLeaderboard();

        if( msg.content != content_new) msg.edit( content_new );
    }

    createLeaderboard(i, max_top)
    {
        //loop through leaderboard data
            //print line of leaderboard message
            this.applyTags(this.leaderboard[i].id, this.leaderboard[i].skill);
    }

    async applytags(id, skill)
    {
         if (!guild)
            return;
        let mem = guild.members.get(id);
        if (!mem)
            return;
        mem.removeRoles(difficulties);
        if (skill < 1500)
            mem.addRole(settler).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 1500 && skill < 1600)
            mem.addRole(chieftain).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 1600 && skill < 1700)
            mem.addRole(warlord).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 1700 && skill < 1800)
            mem.addRole(prince).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 1800 && skill < 1900)
            mem.addRole(king).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 1900 && skill < 2000)
            mem.addRole(emperor).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 2000 && skill < 2100)
            mem.addRole(immortal).catch(console.error);
        else if (skill >= 2100)
            mem.addRole(deity).catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you dont have any `client.on('guildMemberAdd', () =>`

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods that return a Promise need to be called using await and cannot be nested.

```
async function applytags(id, skill)
{
     if (!guild)
        return;
    let mem = await guild.members.get(id);
    if (!mem)
        return;
    await mem.removeRoles(difficulties);
    if (skill < 1500)
        await mem.addRole(settler).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 1500 && skill < 1600)
        await mem.addRole(chieftain).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 1600 && skill < 1700)
        await mem.addRole(warlord).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 1700 && skill < 1800)
        await mem.addRole(prince).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 1800 && skill < 1900)
        await mem.addRole(king).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 1900 && skill < 2000)
        await mem.addRole(emperor).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 2000 && skill < 2100)
        await mem.addRole(immortal).catch(console.error);
    else if (skill >= 2100)
        await mem.addRole(deity).catch(console.error);
}
```

1. https://anidiots.guide/other-guides/async-await
2. https://hackernoon.com/javascript-promises-and-why-async-await-wins-the-battle-4fc9d15d509f
3. https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function