# EventEmitter Javascript limitation problem with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, eventemitter

Good morning, everyone. I hesitated before coming here, but the answers I found didn't match with my specific problem.

I code a Bot Discord in Javascript and I'm doing a maintenance system. For that, I give a precise role to all the players, which prevents any action from their part during the maintenance. The only problem with this is that the server I'm working on is hosting about a hundred players, and more are coming. So I'm looking for a solution to this problem: when I give the same role to all players, Node.js has a blockage that stops the "add role" event from 11 times.

Here is a piece of the error with the same code that repeats itself as many times as there are players.

[image: Click here to see the image]

The code i'm working on is the following one :

```js
...
} else if (args[0] == 'maintenanceon') {
            if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••Développeur") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••ADMINISTRATEUR")) {
                var membersWithRole1 = message.guild.roles.get("666026501472518167").members;
                var membersWithRole2 = message.guild.roles.get("666051237543673877").members;
                var membersWithRole3 = message.guild.roles.get("667770156730155028").members;
                var membersWithRole4 = message.guild.roles.get("661281161334620181").members;
                var membersWithRole5 = message.guild.roles.get("665287396740300810").members;
                var membersWithRole6 = message.guild.roles.get("667038859149705219").members;
                var membersWithRole7 = message.guild.roles.get("664966379954241545").members;
                var membersWithRole8 = message.guild.roles.get("665306076610035723").members;
                var membersWithRole9 = message.guild.roles.get("661900218102448160").members;
                var membersWithRole10 = message.guild.roles.get("661286020599382018").members;

                membersWithRole1.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole2.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole3.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole4.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole5.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole6.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole7.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole8.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole9.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
                membersWithRole10.forEach((member, key) => member.addRole("661944276564836363"));
            }

        } else if (args[0] == 'maintenanceoff') {
            if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••Développeur") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••ADMINISTRATEUR")) {
                var membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.get("661944276564836363").members;

                membersWithRole.forEach((member, key) => member.removeRole("661944276564836363"));
            }
        }
```

I already tried to solve the problem by looking for things like this :

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.setMaxListeners(0);
```

But nothing I tried is working and i'm hopeless. Thanks for reading and I hope I'll solve this problem soon enough.

--Max.

Comment: You probably don't need 11 or more `GuildMemberUpdate` listeners. Please show your code which is assigning the roles/adding the listeners.

Comment: Here is the code
```js
var membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.get("661944276564836363").members;
membersWithRole.forEach((member, key) => member.removeRole("661944276564836363"));
```

Comment: So why you need to use EventEmitter() ? 

Discord works fine , in each of 100000 members role update with no error. So 100 or more members i`ts no problem

Comment: @Max094Reikeb The code in your comment isn't the source of the error you posted. Please edit your original post and add the relevant details.

Comment: @Cipher no it doesn't work "fine" click on the original post to see the error!
ChrisSatchell yes the code I posted is the source of the error, but yes i'm gonna edit the original post.

Comment: Why  you add 11 event listening `GuildMemberUpdate ` ? for what you need that`s match?

Comment: @Cipher i'm looking for every player who has roles I added the ID. And I'm giving them a role so they can't do anything while in maintenance. When I do &maintenanceoff, I'm looking for every player with this role and I'm taking the role away.

Comment: So you don’t need that’s match of listen that’s event , show pls your guild member update  code block

Comment: @Cipher I don't have one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot having trouble adding lots of roles... complains about event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624407/discord-bot-having-trouble-adding-lots-of-roles-complains-about-event-listene)

Answer (score 0):

I think thats can be fixed by add `.catch()` or `await` block.

And if you better way for command `maintenanceon` its get all members who have one of your roles and then give them your role.

```
} else if (args[0] == 'maintenanceon') {
            if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••Développeur") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••ADMINISTRATEUR")) {
                let membersIncludeRole = message.guild.members.filter(member =>  {
                    member.roles.some(r=>["666026501472518167", "666051237543673877", "667770156730155028", "661281161334620181","665287396740300810","667038859149705219","664966379954241545","665306076610035723","661900218102448160","661286020599382018"].includes(r.id))
                })
                let targetRole = message.guild.roles.get('661944276564836363')
                membersIncludeRole.map(member => {
                    if(!member.roles.some(role => role.id === '661944276564836363')) {
                        await member.addRole(targetRole).catch()
                    }
                })
            }

        } else if (args[0] == 'maintenanceoff') {
            if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••Développeur") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "••ADMINISTRATEUR")) {
                var membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.get("661944276564836363").members;

                membersWithRole.forEach((member, key) => await member.removeRole("661944276564836363").catch());
            }
        }
```

Comment: **Note**: In very large guilds it's possible that not all members have already been downloaded and therefore `guild.members` may not be complete.

Comment: Hmm, For what number of members?
How discord can return promise In which there is no part of the members?

Comment: Check https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#identify. Most Discord libraries allow you to download all members though.

Comment: Are you sure thats limit cover on bots auth ?

Comment: await doesn't work, it needs to be in an async function

Comment: @Cipher Yep: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/dev/src/Discord.Net.WebSocket/DiscordSocketConfig.cs#L73
@Max094Reikeb Then make the function `async`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: This is quite useful information , thx you. It is necessary to study this issue in more detail, because I did not encounter similar problems in the guild where the number of participants is more than 1000

Comment: I think you use 

`bot.on('message', message => {` so you can add `bot.on('message', async message => {`

Comment: its`bot.on('message''` block or command file if you use discord collection to handle command. Try this `membersWithRole.forEach( async (member, key) => await member.removeRole("661944276564836363").catch());`